# How to monitor Memory and Disk utilization of Auto Scaling Groups in aws cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-auto-scaling

I need to gather the memory and disk metrics of the autoscaling group in aws cloudwatch.

Can anyone provide me the docs ?

Thanks .

I tried for ec2 instance able to gather the disk and memory metrics .

But unable to do for autoscaling groups.

Answer (score 0):

To collect operating system-level metrics like disk and used memory, you must install the CloudWatch agent.

To Configure monitoring for Auto Scaling instances, Kindly refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/enable-as-instance-metrics.html).